# How to copy source of web-pages with absolute URL in source instead of relative paths?

Tags: firefox, path, firefox-extensions

### Summary

How I can to copy source of web page with absolute URL in source instead of relative paths? Preferable — Firefox, but any others solutions would be nice too.

---

---

### Examples

Page: **http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/planetarium_demo.html**
Source of page: `view-source:http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/planetarium_demo.html`

**Actual behavior**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="planetarium/jquery.planetarium.js"></script>
<link href='planetarium/planetarium.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/demo.css">
<script src="../js/demo.js"></script>
```

**Expected behavior**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/planetarium/jquery.planetarium.js"></script>
<link href='http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/planetarium/planetarium.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.thepetedesign.com/css/demo.css">
<script src="http://www.thepetedesign.com/js/demo.js"></script>
```

---

---

### Justification

If I view source of pages, I usually want edit and preview code of page in my text editor or in [**codepen.io**](http://codepen.io) site, but I need every time change relative paths to full URL. It takes a lot of time.

---

---

### Do not offer

I want to show result for others users, not only for me. Therefore, please, do not offer:

1. Firefox [**Web Console**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console) or [**Firebug**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug/). I can not show my editing in Web Console/Firebug results for others users.
2. Saving web pages. If I save web pages, js/css files was saved in my computer and relative links convert to links of my computer. I can not to show my local files for others users.

But if is it possible save web page with convert relative links to absolute URL's, it would be nice solution.

---

---

### Not helped

1. I search Firefox addons, for example, by keyword [**view source**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/search/?q=view+source&appver=49.0&platform=windows), I download addons, for example, [**View Source**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/view-source/?src=search), but I not find addon with needed function.
2. I find [**bookmarklet**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7544757/5951529). This is the best solution that I could find, but [**not all links to convert correct**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544550/javascript-regex-to-change-all-relative-urls-to-absolute/7544757#comment68444935_7544757) and now this bookmarklet [**not supported**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544550/javascript-regex-to-change-all-relative-urls-to-absolute/7544757#comment54964708_7544757).

Comment: What happens if you just save the page? There isn't going to magic that does it by just copying the code. Also if you just want to have a quit view of how changes might look, consider using the built-in tools in modern browsers (F12).

Comment: @Seth, I [**update**](http://superuser.com/posts/1145876/revisions) my answer. I find [**«magic» bookmarklet**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7544757/5951529), but not all links convert correct. Thanks.